# How to name this cyclic compound with an O in it?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

> How to name this cyclic compound with an O in it?

I was going to name it cyclobutane, but not all of the atoms making up the ring are carbons, one is an oxygen. So, then I decided to name it butane, but that doesn't make sense because there is a ring.

[image]

Comment: This is $1,4$-epoxy butane.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, the molecule you draw is [**tetrahydrofuran**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahydrofuran), aka THF, but of course the only way you can guess that is if you already know the molecule. It's a very common organic solvent.

If you didn't know its common name, you could try to name it according to IUPAC nomenclature. It's an [ether](http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/351/orgnom/ethers/ethers-01.html), and it's cyclic, so it can be named as **oxacyclopentane**. But IUPAC has specific names for cyclic ethers, which in this case is **oxolane**:

[image]

(from [this organic chemistry book](http://books.google.com/books?id=rxRHzOS-3xoC)).